# How to generate random number in a range in makefile?

Tags: python, random, makefile

I'm implementing a server-client chatroom in python. When debugging in localhost, it is annoying to wait until the debugged port is free when the threads are shutdown. How can I have a random number for port number within range `[1023, 65535)` in my makefile?

Comment: Maybe it would be cleaner to apply `SO_REUSEADDR` to your listening socket?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using python anyway, you could just call python from the Makefile using make's `shell` function to generate a random number and save that into a makefile variable.

Here's an example (using Python 3 syntax)

```
RANDINT=$(shell python -c 'from random import randint; print(randint(1023, 65535));')
```

Now you can use `RANDINT` in your makefile. This rule will just print it to the console:

```
random:
        @echo $(RANDINT)
```

More info on makefile variables [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_6.html). Also note there may be a better way, I'm no makefile wizard, this is just the first working solution I hit.

EDIT: just found [this](http://blogs.kgsoft.co.uk/2014_01_15_prg.htm), which is using almost the exact same approach.

Comment: It may also be worth doing `random.Random(seed).randint(1023, 65535)` if you have a seed (e.g. a `BUILD_NUMBER` in CI) that should be consistent across multiple `make` invocations.